# How can I make this javascript marquee manually scrollable?

Tags: javascript, css, marquee

I am trying to make an automatic scrolling marquee using javascript and CSS but, I also want to be able to manually scroll the marquee with the mouse wheel. The marquee functions as expected ie. it scrolls automatically and loops well but I can't figure out how to incorporate manual scrolling. Here is the code that I am using. Any ideas?

```
<doctype HTML>
<body onload="init()">
    <main>
        <div id="marquee_replacement" class="scrollbar" onmouseout="startit();" onmouseover="stop();">
            <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
            <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
            <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>  
            <p>images are also present</p>
            <p class="spacer"></p>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            //
            var speed = 2; // change scroll speed with this value
            /**
             * Initialize the marquee, and start the marquee by calling the marquee function.
             */
            function init() {
                var el = document.getElementById("marquee_replacement");
                el.style.overflow = 'hidden'; //issue is fixed by setting this to auto
                scrollFromBottom();
            }

            var go = 0;
            var timeout = '';
            /**
             * This is where the scroll action happens.
             * Recursive method until stopped.
             */
            function scrollFromBottom() {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
                var el = document.getElementById("marquee_replacement");
                if (el.scrollTop >= el.scrollHeight - 150) {
                    el.scrollTop = 0;
                };
                el.scrollTop = el.scrollTop + speed;
                if (go == 0) {
                    timeout = setTimeout(scrollFromBottom, 50);
                };
            }

            /**
             * Set the stop variable to be true (will stop the marquee at the next pass).
             */
            function stop() {
                go = 1;
            }

            /**
             * Set the stop variable to be false and call the marquee function.
             */
            function startit() {
                go = 0;
                scrollFromBottom();
            }
        </script>

        <!--CSS for Marquee-->
        <style type="text/css">
            #marquee_replacement.scrollbar {
                width: auto;
                height: 150px;
                overflow-y: scroll; /*issue is fixed by setting this to auto*/
            }

            .scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
                display: none;
            }

            #marquee_replacement {
                -ms-overflow-style: none;
                /* IE and Edge */
                scrollbar-width: none;
                /* Firefox */
            }

            #marquee_replacement p.spacer {
                height: 150px;
            }
        </style>
    </main>
</body>
```

Edit:
Sorry for the newbie mistake of not providing a minimal reproducible example. I will update the code above to provide an MREX so that the issue is easier to understand for future readers. Also, I solved the issue. If I set the overflow values in both CSS and javascript portions to auto instead of scroll and hidden respectively it works as an auto-scrolling marquee and manual scrolling text box.

Comment: The HTML looks like...? Could you please provide a [mcve]? Also, where do you `init()` it? Or `startit()` ??

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` takes a function, not a string with code. Do it like this: `setTimeout(scrollFromBottom, 50)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I implemented this change and it improved the scrolling of the marquee but I still am unsure of how to manually scroll the marquee, in addition, to automatically scroll it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If anyone needs this in the future I had to set `el.style.overflow = 'auto';`to auto instead of hidden and set the CSS overflow to `overflow-y: auto;` to auto instead of scroll. Now it scrolls automatically and manually!